# Should I use CASE WHEN or IIF? Are subqueries a possible part of the solution?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, case, iif

I'm using My SQL (latest version) and I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE COURSES (
IDCOURSE INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL, 
HOURS INT,
PRICE FLOAT (10,2) NOT NULL, 
ID_PREREQ INT
);

ALTER TABLE COURSES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PREREQ
FOREIGN KEY (ID_PREREQ) REFERENCES COURSES (IDCOURSE);
```

What I want do is: select the columns NAME, HOURS, PRICE and ID_PREREQ AS REQUISITES.
Whenever ID_PREREQ is NULL, I want to read "NO REQUISITES". If else, then I want to read whatever's in the associated NAME column.

For example:

If this is my table:

| IDCOURSE | NAME | HOURS | PRICE | ID_PREREQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RELATIONAL DB | 20 | 400.00 | NULL |
| 2 | BUSINESS INTELLIGENCE | 40 | 800.00 | 1 |
| 3 | ADVANCED DB | 20 | 600.00 | 2 |
| 4 | PROGRAMMING | 20 | 400.00 | NULL |

I'd like a select to show me this:

| NAME | HOURS | PRICE | REQUISITES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RELATIONAL DB | 20 | 400.00 | NO REQUISITES |
| BUSINESS INTELLIGENCE | 40 | 800.00 | RELATIONAL DB |
| ADVANCED DB | 20 | 600.00 | BUSINESS INTELLIGENCE |
| PROGRAMMING | 20 | 400.00 | NO REQUISITES |

What I've tried so far:

[image]

With this solution, I came across two different problems:

**1. How to show the NAME related to the correct ID_PREREQ?**

I managed to write the following code:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ID_PREREQ IS NOT NULL
    THEN NAME
    ELSE 'NO REQUISITES'
END
FROM COURSES;
```

But as you can see, I'm merely repeting the name column in the REQUISITES column, instead of getting the associated value I want. I was also unable to give the result column its proper name (REQUISITES).

**2. How to select more columns besides the REQUISITES column?**

I've tried this:

[image]

But for some reason I got a syntax error.

Finally, I also tried the IIF Statement because the syntax seemed easier, but I got an ERROR 1305: FUNCTION does not exist.

I don't understand why is that, considering that I'm using the latest MySQL version and apparently that IIF statement was released in 2012.

Can somebody please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: `Float` is *never* the correct data type for monetary values.

Comment: @Stu could you explain why not? I have seen it used many times, that information comes as a surprise :o

Comment: It's an imprecise data type [unsuitable for use for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extract the corresponding prerequisite along with the course, you need to apply a `SELF JOIN` operation. Among the join kinds, you could use a `LEFT JOIN` to keep the courses with no prerequisites. Then the [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function will allow you to substitute your NULL values with a string of your choice (like "*NO REQUISITES*").

```
SELECT c1.IDCOURSE,
       c1.NAME,
       c1.HOURS,
       c1.PRICE,
       COALESCE(c2.NAME, 'NO REQUISITES') AS REQUISITES
FROM      COURSES c1
LEFT JOIN COURSES c2
       ON c1.ID_PREREQ = c2.IDCOURSE 
ORDER BY IDCOURSE
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fjvYCFyd6YgchmesaS1iAK/0).

**Side Note**: MySQL's `IIF` function is named [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if).